# Can't login as root anymore

Tags: login, password, root

I wanted to change my username, and tried out this explanation here: https://askubuntu.com/a/205470/112035.

First, I changed the username in /etc/passwd to the new one. Then I wanted to change it at /etc/group too, but since changing it at the first file I can't login as root anymore.

Is there a way to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hm, did you backup these files by any chance?

Comment: do **sudo nautilus** in terminal and proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to get root privileges at boot time. Then you can revert the change you made and reset the password on the primary account.

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Be very careful changing usernames. /etc/passwd associates each username with a user ID (number). In some places in the system the number is used, in others the name. To change a username without breaking things you therefore have to change the name everywhere it occurs. I would recommend that you not try to change your username unless you are an expert. If you are an expert then I don't have to tell you about usermod(8).  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'we lost my root acsess, but can login in ubuntu...

Solved with this metod:

Reboot in to recovery mode and 
to get Read/Write enabled done this

```
mount -o rw,remount /
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
chown root /etc/sudoers
```

Than added me to root user with this

```
sudo adduser <my username> sudo
```

When you replace my username with yours (without the <>)

To check username do this

```
ls /home
```

To change your password do this

```
passwd <your password>
```

When you replace my password with yours (without the <>)

When done youst type`reboot`
and you are done...

p.s. sorry for my bad English?!

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the computer into recovery mode (esc to grub and enter root prompt) and do

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
chown root /etc/sudoers
```

Reboot back to desktop and run in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

This will bring you through a series of menus to allow you to reconfigure all your packages and should fix any permissions issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could someone verify this?

In UNIX systems you also have an important file called `/etc/shadow`. Inside that file, you have encrypted password for each user. I think that you changed the files `/etc/group` and `/etc/passwd` but forgot to change the `/etc/shadow`. So now, you have changed a username, but you don't have actually a password for it. I am just theorizing here.

For example I created a `dummy` account, with `dummy` password. My contents of files are:

```
/etc/shadow
dummy:$6$ddvrCSTQ$4cAt8U.3sd6TQZ8Xi4VzOQv/GR7LA/bi72di9RE5v77y2U7os60DKbb0VLS.JPslf3g9GBBBzbNqW0y5ynkc11:15687:0:99999:7:::

/etc/group
dummy:x:1001:

/etc/passwd
dummy:x:1001:1001::/home/dummy:/bin/sh
```

Now I will remove the entry from `/etc/shadow` file. This is what I get:

```
su dummy
Password: <I type dummy here>
su: Authentication failure
```

So there you have it. You should generate a proper hash for your new user and it to `/etc/shadow`. Hope that helps.